# Django Social Auth - Google login

Tags: django

I want to use Django Social Auth for getting logged in a website using a Google account. But I am unable to find a good tutorial and the tutorials available are not very clear. What are the changes required in Settings.py and what should be the value of keys like GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY and GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET?

Comment: look at http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/google.html